# Why does Android Studio don't "accept" "getBoolean"?

Tags: android, boolean

It just says: "Cannot resolve symbol "getBoolean""

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "write";

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {
    //the app is being launched for first time, do something
    Log.d("Comments", "First time");


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, firststart.class);


    settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit();
}
```

Comment: try to clean project

Comment: Did unfortunately not work.